# Win32 Exception while running my VB application on different devices

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, frameworks, win32-process

Good evening,
Please I'm doing an application in VB that opens a file. Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyClass.Click
    Dim myProc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\ex.txt" 'The file in a flash drive
    myProc.Start()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
End Class
```

The thing is that the program works very well for me (I have the latest version of .NET Framework), but, when I try it in another office, it gives that exception "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception 0x80004005 : The system cannot find the file specified".
Please, how can I get it working in another device (x86 or x64, with or without the latest version of .net framework) ?
Thank you.

**UPDATE 1 :**
I added the exception code : 0x80004005

**UPDATE 2 :**
I just edited the path in my code, because the old one was just to explain my question, but it seemed that it was a very bad idea, so, I just modified the path to the real path in my projet (E:\ex.txt)

Comment: what does your Imports section in the header look like also are you manually adding that reference to the References node in your project..? also make sure that the target machine has the .NET Framework installed on it.. google for how to install the latest .Net Framework

Comment: Did you try compiling/debugging it in different modes (`x86` and `x64`) and see if that worked?

Comment: 1- I have no imports in the header,
2- I didn't understand well the second point,
3- That's my question, I want to work it in many devices that the .NET is not installed or doesn"t exist!

Comment: In fact, I know that the frameworks should been installed in the devices, I just want to make sure that this is the only problem that makes the application nonworking.

Comment: you need to look at the comment posted by @devRicher you can't assume all machines have the same operating system on them.. do a simple google search on how to configure .net application project to run on `AnyCPU`

Comment: @MethodMan I've tried it in the "Configuration manager"! Still doesn't working! Sorry if it seems that I didn't did a research effort, but, I'm working on that for 6 nights! Sorry!

Comment: @Hamza_PUMP.MA The error is pretty clear. There is no file at that path. You cannot expect every computer to have that file in that exact path.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn"t explain it very well! You can see the code updated and you"ll see!
In fact, the file is going to be in a flash drive (USB).

Comment: Like @CodingYoshi says you cannot expect `C:\Users\Desktop\ex.txt` to exist on every computer (you also seem to be missing a user name in there). Look into [**`Environment.GetFolderPath()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Hamza_PUMP.MA this is why you do not hardcode paths and if you do decide to do that you should write code to check If Directory.Exist or not and if not create the directory `6 nights` come on that's pretty obvious as well from the error message I would suggest look for some more free basic .net tutorials online.. thanks

Comment: @MethodMan Thank you for your answer! I'll try my best! thank you guys again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drive letters are not always the same on all machines especially with removable storage.
[`System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives) can be used to get information on all logical drives and find the file:

```vb
For Each driveInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives ' loop all logical drives on the computer 

    If driveInfo.DriveType = System.IO.DriveType.Removable Then ' optional check if removable storage device 

        Dim fileInfos = driveInfo.RootDirectory.GetFiles("ex.txt") ' search for driveLetter:\ex.txt 

        If fileInfos.Length > 0 Then

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileInfos(0).FullName) ' start the file 

            Exit For  ' optional to leave the For loop 

        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @Slai for your answer! It worked very well!
In fact, the whole problem was in the drive letters in the file's path!